# Proving $(n+1)c^{1/(n+1)} - nc^{1/n} \le 1$ from first principles

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Is it possible to prove that
\begin{align*}
(n+1)c^{1/(n+1)} - nc^{1/n} \le 1 \qquad c \in \mathbb{R}_+, n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{align*}
using only elementary techniques? (No calculus, no appeasement to Jensen's inequality).

**Motivation**
The problem I originally encountered was to prove that, if $x_1, \cdots, x_n > 0$ and $y_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i} - n(\prod_{i=1}^{n}{x_i})^{1/n}$, then $(y_n)$ is a monotonically increasing sequence. If we prove this, then our results would imply
\begin{align*}
A_{n+1} - G_{n+1} \ge \frac{n}{n+1}(A_n - G_n)
\end{align*}
where $A_n, G_n$ are the arithmetic and geometric means, respectively, of the first $n$ terms. Simple induction would instantly give us a proof of the AM-GM inequality. Other [solutions](http://math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/problem_solving/putnam/training-ineq.pdf) (#33) use the AM-GM inequality itself in proving the statement, while my search for an independent proof not using AM-GM arrived at the inequality you see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0<a<1$ then $a^n$ is less than each of $a^0,a^1,\dotsc,a^{n-1}$, so
$$ na^n < \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^k = \frac{1-a^n}{1-a} \tag{1} $$
Multiplying by $1-a$, which is positive, we get
$$ n(a^n-a^{n+1}) < 1-a^n \tag{2} $$
If, on the other hand, $a>1$, then the inequality (1) will be reversed, but since $1-a$ is negative, the inequality (2) will hold as written.

Rearranging (2), we have
$$ (n+1)a^n - na^{n+1} < 1 $$
when $a>0$ and $a\ne 1$; taking $a=c^{1/n(n+1)}$ yields your inequality.